# Login failed after installing IE8 on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer, login, internet-explorer-8, user-accounts

I  can't login to Windows XP after installing Internet Explorer 8.

I installed the software from Microsoft under it prompted me to reboot. After the reboot I'm asked for the user password but the PC is stuck at the `loading your personal settings screen`.

What should I do?

Comment: How long have you let it set at that screen?

Answer (score 0):

If it fails to load, see if the PC will start in safe mode with networking. If it does see if IE8 will load, Go to control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced Tab, hit the Reset button, shut down and try a normal boot again.

You may be infected

Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

Answer (score -1):

You may be using WIndows.. Hehe yes thats the big problem..
Maybe u installed it with virus and from place witch gave u this installation was not real windows website but hacker made website.
Forget windows.
Backup ur files bookmarks emails.
Install ubuntu and u wont have viruses and wont need antivirus programm and all will work. ;)
Get it at ubuntu.com
Its free
BTW you dont have to install Ubuntu to just try it. Just download ubuntu.iso from ubuntu.com and burn to cd and put cd in PC and choose live version. Its without installing but slower couse from CD.
If no cd then u can in ubuntu.com check on download to see how to make usb version